# Using Component vs Directives

Tags: jquery, angular, angularjs-directive

I using a JQuery Library (iCheck) for my html component .. So when I use a component fot inject it in my html component it's work fine .. like my code

ww.component.ts

```
import { ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, Component } from '@angular/core';

declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-icheck',
  templateUrl: 'icheck.component.html'
})
export class ICheck implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('input') input;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    jQuery(this.input.nativeElement).iCheck({
       checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-aero',
       radioClass: 'iradio_square-aero'
    });
  }
}
```

And for use it in an other component :

```
<my-icheck></my-icheck>
```

The result :[image]

Now when I use a directive like :
my-directive.ts

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

declare var jQuery: any;

@Directive({
  selector: '[icheck]'
})

export class IcheckDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  // @ViewChild('input') input;
   @Input() input;
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    jQuery(this.input.nativeElement).iCheck({
       checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-aero',
       radioClass: 'iradio_square-aero'
    });
}}
```

And for use it in a html component :
ww.component.html

```
<label class="radio icheck-inline menu-label">
    <input icheck type="radio" name="aa" value="ANN"> BUTTON RADIO
</label>
```

with **icheck** the name of my selector I have not the same result : 
[image]

Some have an issue ?

Comment: Yes you right..but it does not resolve it

Comment: It s work ... thx